# netbeans ftp configuration

Tags: netbeans, ftp

I've set up my FTP connection for my project, but when it uploads the file, it adds a directory named after the project to the uploads (which means it isn't going to the right folder). 
i.e.

initial directory set to '/httpdocs'; 
no upload directory specified.

I upload a file from my local folder: 
project name/library/script.php 
I want it to go here: 
FTP/httpdocs/library/script.php

but it's going here:

FTP/httpdocs/PROJECTNAME/library/script.php

Can anyone help me get this configured correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you are making your project in netbeans one folder too high. The project should be created with the main folder being the root folder, not the folder that holds the root folder (the one with the name of the folder).

So, you need to recreate your project with the correct folder being the root folder, and you should be all set.